# How to insert value from an array to an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I might need some help on JavaScript about array stuff.

```
[
"URL_1",
"URL_2",
"URL_3",
"URL_4",
...,
"URL_30"
]
```

Let's just say these above are an array of strings which are links and how do I move them to an array object like this below?

```
[
  {
    url: "URL_1"
  },
  {
    url: "URL_2"
  },
  {
    url: "URL_3"
  },
...,
  {
    url: "URL_30"
  }
]
```

Comment: `urls.map(url => ({ url }))` is a naive one-liner.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [ "URL_1", "URL_2", "URL_3", "URL_4", "URL_30" ];

const res = arr.map(url => ({ url }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if I want eg. [{ book: { url: "URL_1" } }, { book: { url: "URL_2" } }] ??

Comment: ``arr.map(url => ({ book: { url } }))``

Answer (score -1):

simply:

```
    let temp = [];
    yourArray.foreach((val) =>{
    temp.push({val})
})
    yourArray = temp;
```